# Google Analytics Event Tracking and Variable visibility

Tags: google-analytics

I have added to my html page the standard latest snippet to get google analytics to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-15080849-1']); 
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 
  (function() { 
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
    ga.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga); 
  })(); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now looking at the official 'event tracking guide' google says:

Add a snippet such as:

```
pageTracker._trackEvent('Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind');
```

where is pageTracker coming from? Is it a global object in `ga.js`? If it is, why does google not tell me that they run a risk of breaking some script?

Answer (score 3):

You are using [the async version of GA](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html).

So your event tracking code should use that syntax. Instead of `pageTracker._trackEvent('Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind');`, you will want something like `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);`

Also, you can see more about the tracking method here (I can't post a second link yet):

code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEventTracking.html

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The migration guide for async analytics describes how to do event tracking asynchronously:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html#EventTracking

pageTracker is the global that most people use when using the traditional GA syntax.  You don't need to use it for asynchronous GA.  Instead you want:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I've been struggling with this all week.